Specify word delimiters for macOS (14+), such that cursor movement/selection in all applications are affected?
How can I specify word delimiters (word boundaries) for macOS (14+), such that cursor movement/selection in all applications are affected?
Methods mentioned on this site (A, B) appear to no longer be valid or apply solely to specific applications (A, B, C). I have not found any third-party applications.
